# Separating results in chartjs line chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chart.js

So, I have a form with a starting date, an end date and a selector so you can choose which server (selected by id) you'd like to select data from, and returns a json string with the day, temperature and server id. everything works just fine here.

My issue comes when I tried to make it so when you don't select a server, it gives you all data from all servers (`select stuff from table where id like '%'`). I adapted my chart generating function to this:

```
function generateChart(data) {
    var results = JSON.parse(data);
    if (results.error == true) {
        var errCode = results.code;
        var errText = results.text;
        defineError(errCode, errText);
    }
    else {
        var chartjsTemp = [];
        var chartjsDate = [];
        if (results.length > 1) {
            for (var i = 1; i < results.length; i++) {
                chartjsTemp.push(results[i].probeTemp);
                chartjsDate.push(results[i].dateProbe);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert ("No results!");
        }
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var button = $("#submitButton");
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
            myChart.destroy();
        });
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: chartjsDate,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'temp',
                    data: chartjsTemp,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(240,240,240,0.5)"
                }]
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know how to adapt the datasets part so if I have an unknown number of servers with different values for data, (might return 3 servers or 5 different servers, depending on the database used) to be generated automatically instead of having to do a dataset for every existing server (which means I'd have to do a function for each database with each server).

Edit: This is an example of what happens if I leave it like this (which obviously is not good): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLjRe.jpg

Edit 2: Okay, doing a for loop like this:

```
for (i=0; i >= chartjsId.length; i++) {
datasets: [{
    label: chartjsId[i],
    data: chartjsTemp,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(240,240,240,0.5)"
}]
}
```

didn't work much at all. I get a slim framework error.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, you have draw all the charts you want and know you want to hide all other and show the selected ones.
We can achieve this through Legends, when user click on the legend its display will toggle from graph.

Or we can achieve like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mastersmind/rsvk12d6/2/)

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "First",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,20,20,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,20,20,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 90]
    }, {
        label: "Second",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(15,187,25,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(15,187,25,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [38, 55, 50, 65, 35, 67, 54]
    }]
};

var options = {
    // String - Template string for single tooltips
    tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label %>: <%}%><%= value + ' %' %>",
    // String - Template string for multiple tooltips
    multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= value + ' %' %>",
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

window.myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
window.myLineChart.store = new Array();


$('#selectbox').change(function () {
    var label = $('#selectbox').val();
    var chart = window.myLineChart;
    var store = chart.store;
    var finded = false;

    //Restore all
    for (var i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
      var restored = store.splice(i, 1)[0][1];
      chart.datasets.push(restored);
    }
    //Если нет, то добавляем в стор
    if (label!='All') {
        console.log('Start search dataset with label = ' + label);
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.datasets.length; i++) {
            if (chart.datasets[i].label === label) {
                chart.store.push([label, chart.datasets.splice(i, 1)[0]]);
            }
        }
    }
    chart.update();
});
```

Comment: Yes, and no. I want to avoid having to set "First" and "Second". Assuming I have X ammount of datasets (could be "First", "Second" and "Third", or it could go as high to a "Fifth" one), I want to avoid having to set all of their names and data by myself, since I have a few databases with different ammount of datasets. Thanks for the answer, though. I will see if I can use something from there.

Comment: how the user can select?

Comment: using multi selectbox?

Comment: No, it's a regular select box, and if you don't select anything, the database changes the id from an integer to '%' to select everything. Multi select box is something I was planning to add once I manage to get this working.

Comment: Ok, but u can fill that selectbox dynamically (first, second ... nth).
when it changes it pass u the name which corresponds the "label" in the graph.

Comment: I edited my question with that. I tried with a for loop to throw the data and name, but it didn't quite work.

Comment: I just thought about a possible solution. My json strings look like this `{id: "3", probeTemp: "35.40", dateProbe: "2015-08-25"}`, where id is n. I should group all results by id, instead of leaving it inside the json, otherwise I think I'm in for a bad time. I will now look for a way to do it.